# How to insert data into a mysql table extracted from a form, with nodeJs - express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, express

I know that in theory I have to extract the data with body-parser somehow like this.

```
 <form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="user[name]">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 app.use(express.bodyParser());

  app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body.user.name);
  });
```

I want to extract and insert the data into a mysql table like I've done it before in php, like this.

```
 $user_name = addslashes ($_POST['user_name']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_something (user_name) VALUES ('$user_name')";
  etc...
```

My real question is, what is the most actual, and professional way to achieve it? How can I safely pass the extracted dataobject to the mysql property?

Comment: did you check this packages ?
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysql
they have a greet docs

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have configured the connection with Nodejs called mysqlConnection.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.post('/', function(request, response){

        var Query = "INSERT INTO tb_something (user_name) VALUES ('"+request.body.user.name+"')";
        mysqlConnection.query(Query, function(error, result){

            //Here you can handle the result
            if(error){
                return response.status(500).send('Error 500') 
            }else{
                if(result.length !== 0){
                    return response.status(400).send('Error 400.');
                }else{
                    return response.status(200).send('All is Ok');
                }
            }

        mysqlConnection.end();
    });
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO tb_something (name) VALUES ('test')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
```